# How to get value from dynamically generated <option> <select> express ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, visual-studio-code, ejs

First of all I thank you for reading and making an attempt to my problem.

I dynamically rendered my  {dropdown} but i was unable to get the selected value at my back-end.

on my form i am also getting photo and the name of suite is dynamically rendered.

Code below if i am doing something incorrect.

Lang - Javascript 
FW - Express Js
Template - EJS

I have body-parse and set to true.

- Issue i cannot get selected value to my back-end using POST request (undefined or null).
- But if i use GET as the action & Request i do get the selected value.

Thank you again. If i am not clear please, i will explain clearly. I am newly NODE JS AND EXPRESS.

-Front-end

```
<form  class="ui form" action="admin/uploadphoto" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">      

      <h2 class=" ui dividing header" style="text-align: center;">Add Images to suites</h2>

      <div class="two fields">
        <div class="field">
          <label>Add Suites Images</label>
            <input name="suiteimage" type="file">
        </div>
        <div class="field">
          <label>Suites*</label>
          <select name="suiteselected" class="ui dropdown">
            <% suites.forEach(function(suite) { %>     
              <option name = "suiteid" value="<%= suite.suite_name %>"><%= suite.suite_name %></option>
              <% })%>

          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
      <input type="submit" class="ui button" tabindex="0" value="Save New Suite">
    </form>
```

- Back-end

```
const uuid = require("uuid/v4");
const { Pool } = require("pg");
const multer = require("multer");


// Insert photo and selected value from dropdown (options)
const PostPhoto = (req, res) => {
  var suiteimage;
  const suite_photo_id = uuid(); 
  const {suiteselected} = req.body;
  console.log( suiteselected + " --ID") //Here i am testing if selected valued is passed

// this is my multer function to config where i need to store my photo path
  upload(req, res, err => {
     suiteimage = req.file.path;
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(suiteimage);
    }
  });


..... //my database query to save my post....

};
```

-route

```
router.post ('/uploadphoto', service.PostPhoto);
``
```

Comment: Can you modify your post to include the function uuid() ?

Comment: Hi @SPlatten, Thank you for replying. I just modified it but, it was an installed uuid(); package

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out the solution to this, body-parse should be required and extended true.

when having text and image as 1 form to be posted to the back-end make sure

- Your image function (upload) is inside the req,res function or the values will be undefine or null.

if you need more explanation to comment.

```
//my post for image and text function
const PostPhoto = (req, res) => {
   const suite_photo_id = uuid(); 

  upload(req, res, function(err) {
    const {suiteselected} = req.body;
    console.log(req.file);
    var imagePath = req.file.path.replace(/^public\//, '');
    console.log( suiteselected + " --ID")
   console.log(imagePath);


   pool.query(
    "INSERT INTO suite_photos (suite_photo_id,suite_photo,suite_id) VALUES($1,$2,$3)",
    [suite_photo_id, imagePath,suiteselected],
    (error, result) => {
      if (error) {
        throw error;
      } else{
        console.log(result);
        res.redirect("/admin");
      }
    }
  );
 });



};
```

That's all that changed.

Thank you all!!!